# Q.all with chained sequence

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I an using [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), and have a series of functions that return promises chained together with then callbacks, because, I need them to execute in order [as a sequence](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#sequences).

```
var promiseOne = one();
promiseOne.then(two).then(three).done();
```

I also have some promise that can happen at any time. I need to know when they have ALL resolved - including the last then call back in the chain of promises.  I was trying to use Q.all.then but it will reach Q.all's then before some of these promises -

```
Q.all([promiseOne, anotherPromise]).then(function(results) {

  // will hit this before chain above is done
});
```

in my jsfiddle example, I just have the one promise in Q.all, but in reality it is one of many.  Is there any way to make this work that that I can know when all, including chained then's, are resolved?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/98rq0bs6/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A promise does not know what was chained to it. However, calling `.then()` does return a new promise which will know what it was chained from. You will need to take this new promise, which represents the result of the chained actions, and wait for it - instead of `promiseOne`, which was only the first link in the chain.

```
var promiseOne = one();
var promiseChain = promiseOne.then(two).then(three);

Q.all([promiseChain, anotherPromise]).then(function(results) {
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ wait for the chain
    …
}).done();
```

Comment: I understand the idea, but not the mechanics of how it's actually working exactly. For example, it seems like as soon as you chain a "then" to a promise, it would know about the chain. If it can't because maybe it's already resolved, it seems like you should not be able to do this.

Comment: The original promise does only know about the handler, and that it has to call it when it resolves. But it doesn't know what this handler does, and not about the new promise which will get resolved with the result of the handler call. In `promiseTwo = promiseOne.then(two)`, when you chain another handler to `promiseOne` it will get called at the same time as `two`. If you want a handler to wait for `two`, and get its return value, you need to chain it to `promiseTwo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var listOfItems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// Creating an empty initial promise that always resolves itself.
var promise = $q.all([]);

// Iterating list of items.
angular.forEach(listOfItems, function (item) {
  promise = promise.then(function () {
    return $timeout(function () {
      console.log('Item executed: ' + item);
    }, 2000);
  });
});

promise.finally(function () {
  console.log('Chain finished!');
});
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/8ee69f447765bc5c5e19), In this solution, "angular.forEach" make possible that each promise be executed in chain, in other words, be a promises´s sequence

Comment: Please do not only copy code from some other page, but also add some explanation text.